# Why does fast graph convolution need Chebyshev polynomials?

Tags: machine-learning, convolution, graph-theory, spectral-analysis, graph-neural-network

I'm reading the paper [*Convolutional Neural Networks on Graphs with Fast Localized Spectral Filtering*](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6081-convolutional-neural-networks-on-graphs-with-fastlocalized-spectral-filtering.pdf) and find it difficult to understand the motivation for using Chebyshev polynomials.

With localized kernels, $g_{\theta}(\Lambda) = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \theta_{k}\Lambda^k$, and the convolution $U g_{\theta}(\Lambda) U^Tf$ becomes $\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\theta_{k}L^kf$.

The paper argues that $U g_{\theta}(\Lambda) U^Tf$ requires $O(n^2)$ operations and therefore proposes Chebyshev polynomials to accelerate the computation.

My question is, although evaluating $U g_{\theta}(\Lambda) U^Tf$ requires $O(n^2)$ operations, an equivalent evaluation $\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\theta_{k}L^kf$ only requires $O(K\mathcal{E})$ ($\mathcal{E}$ is the number of edges). So **why bother using Chebyshev polynomials**?

How to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\theta_{k}L^kf$ within $O(K\mathcal{E})$ operations:

1. $u_o = f$
2. $u_1 = Lu_0$ ($L$ is sparse and so it requires $O(\mathcal{E})$ operations)
3. $u_2 = Lu_1$ ($L$ is sparse and so it requires $O(\mathcal{E})$ operations)

......

$\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\theta_{k}L^kf$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} u_k$ requires $O(K\mathcal{E})$ operations.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is well discussed in https://github.com/mdeff/cnn_graph/issues/35 . Chebyshev polynomials do not bring faster computation. It may bring some minor benefits like parameter orthogonality.